# how to add a table inside another table in bootstrap 3

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

So, I am trying to create an event calendar in HTML. I am trying to have multiple tables inside one big table.

**Here is a simple table:**

```
<table class="table table-bordered">
          <thead>
              <tr>
                  <th>Sun</th>
                  <th>Mon</th>
                  <th>Tue</th>
                  <th>Wed</th>
                  <th>Thu</th>
                  <th>Fri</th>
                  <th>Sat</th>
              </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>

              <tr>

                  <td class=" td-top-text"></td>
                  <td class=" td-top-text"></td>
                  <td class=" td-top-text"></td>
                  <td class=" td-top-text"></td>
                  <td class=" td-top-text">1</td>
                  <td class=" td-top-text">2</td>
                  <td class=" td-top-text">3</td>
              </tr>

              <tr>
                  <td class="td-top-text">4</td>
                  <td class="td-top-text">5</td>
                  <td class="td-top-text">6</td>
                  <td class="td-top-text">7</td>
                  <td class="td-top-text">8</td>
                  <td class="td-top-text">9</td>
                  <td class="td-top-text">10</td>
              </tr>
          </tbody>
      </table>
```

**This is how the table looks now:**

[image: table]

**And this is how I would like to do it:**

[image: table2]

**Please Note,** the colors are just to show what I am trying to do, I don't need a border around the day.

Also, the `red rectangles` are the events/titles for that day.

**And so, the final table would look something like this:**

[image: final table]

but with the small table(s) inside the big table

I am using this webpage as a guide.

[Full Calendar](http://fullcalendar.io/)

[image]
**EDIT:** I just need to implement the `html`

**EDIT and NOTE:** 
The user with the correct answer showed that I don't need tables inside tables to create my event calendar.

Comment: This seems like a CSS problem.  Can you post your CSS?

Comment: Have you considered using one of the bootstrap event calendars found on github?

Comment: The css is same as boostrap i didnt change anything, just make the numbers top and right

Comment: @ZackMacomber can you send me link to that github

Comment: https://github.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=bootstrap+event+calendars

Comment: or just go to https://github.com/ & search for 'bootstrap event calendars'

Comment: @ZackMacomber I will take a look at it... ;)  However, I would love to create my own, in this way I will be able to insert it into my portfolio..So, I hope to get something from this link

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on your screenshots, I made this little snippet for you to check out. The `<td>`'s will be squared at all times, and the events using only one line will line up below the date covering the full width of the square. This uses Bootstrap CSS / classes, but with a few rules to override stuff like padding etc.

```css
.inside-date, .td-top-text {
    text-align: right;
}
.inside-event {
    text-align: left;
}
.inside-event.btn {
    text-align: left;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0px;
    line-height: 1.2em;
}
td.td-top-text {
    width:14.28571428571429%; /* 100% divided by 7 */
    position:relative;
}
td.td-top-text:before {
    content:'';
    display:block;
    margin-top:100%;
    position: relative;
}
td.td-top-text .inside {
    position:absolute;
    top:2px;
    bottom:2px;
    left:2px;
    right:2px;
    overflow-y: auto;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<table class="table table-bordered">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Sun</th>
            <th>Mon</th>
            <th>Tue</th>
            <th>Wed</th>
            <th>Thu</th>
            <th>Fri</th>
            <th>Sat</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td class=" td-top-text"></td>
            <td class=" td-top-text"></td>
            <td class=" td-top-text"></td>
            <td class=" td-top-text"></td>
            <td class=" td-top-text">
                <div class="inside">
                    <div class="inside-date">1</div>
                    <div class="inside-event btn btn-primary" title="Event text 1(shown on hover)">Event text 1</div>
                    <div class="inside-event btn btn-warning" title="Event text 2(shown on hover)">Event text 2</div>
                    <div class="inside-event btn btn-success" title="Event text 3(shown on hover)">Event text 3</div>
                    <div class="inside-event btn btn-primary" title="Event text 4(shown on hover)">Event text 4</div>
                    <div class="inside-event btn btn-warning" title="Event text 5(shown on hover)">Event text 5</div>
                    <div class="inside-event btn btn-success" title="Event text 6(shown on hover)">Event text 6</div>
                    <div class="inside-event btn btn-primary" title="Event text 7(shown on hover)">Event text 7</div>
                    <div class="inside-event btn btn-warning" title="Event text 8(shown on hover)">Event text 8</div>
                    <div class="inside-event btn btn-success" title="Event text 9(shown on hover)">Event text 9</div>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td class=" td-top-text">
              <div class="inside">
                <div class="inside-date">2</div>
                <div class="inside-event btn btn-primary" title="Text fits(shown on hover)">Text fits</div>
                <div class="inside-event btn btn-warning" title="Long event text that absolutely does not fit(shown on hover)">Long event text that absolutely does not fit</div>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td class=" td-top-text">
                <div class="inside">3</div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="td-top-text">
                <div class="inside">4</div>
            </td>
            <td class="td-top-text">
                <div class="inside">5</div>
            </td>
            <td class="td-top-text">
                <div class="inside">6</div>
            </td>
            <td class="td-top-text">
                <div class="inside">7</div>
            </td>
            <td class="td-top-text">
                <div class="inside">8</div>
            </td>
            <td class="td-top-text">
                <div class="inside">9</div>
            </td>
            <td class="td-top-text">
                <div class="inside">10</div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Update: Added hidden horizontal content, and auto scrollable content on vertical content. Also, when mouse over the event, you will see the full description.

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer.  Few questions, so I don't need tables inside table? and `inside` will hold all my events/person_name?

Comment: No, you don't need tables inside the table. `inside` will hold all your events, but as you can imagine, if there are more events than what can fit into your daily square, they will be hidden(`overflow-y: auto; overflow-x: hidden;` on `inside` might be what you want there). Did you want squares like in your screenshot, or would you prefer it if the `<td>` extended (including the full week) when there were too many events?

Comment: Yes please, I would love to extended it.  I will be using tutors names, so not sure how many tutors will be available per day, could be only 3 or maybe 6 and students should be able to see all tutors per day.  I will implement the `week` and `day` later to include `times` to it.  Thanks

Comment: I did a quick fix on my post to show you how you could do it. Would that be preferred to keep the ratio of the square boxes?

Comment: Not sure if is because I have a mac, but I cant see that there are more than 3 events unless I scroll down.  What I mean is the scroll down bar doesn't show up unless I scroll it down.  I think that students can wouldn't that there are more events under the third one =/.  We are complicate some time. What do you think we can do to let students know that there are more than 3 events?  i think that by just showing the bar will be fine.

Comment: By the way, and yes this is the right answer so +50 +15 +10

Comment: Did you check out the most recent update to my post? On the 1st of the month there are a scrollbar, on the 2nd of the month there are not because there are only two events. The scrollbar will only show up if there are too many events. Glad you are happy with the solution, thanks. :)

Comment: yes i know, maybe because im using mac or maybe is the `test tool` that doesn't show the bar unless you move the mouse.  =) thanks, you will get your 50 reputations in 5 hours, according to stackoverflow rules n stuffs, doesn't let me give it to you until 5 hours.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95183/discussion-between-ariel-maduro-and-turbopipp).